# How to retrieve friend list from a database with 2 tables

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have two tables one with users and one where i link them when a friend request is sent. The problem is that i didn't manage to make a good query to retrive the user friend list corectly. ID_User1 is the one who sends the request and ID_User2 the one who accepts. Status_Link has two values 1=pending 2=friends. So when i select an user i want to display his friend list with fname and lname.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Friends` (
  `ID_Link_Users` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_User1` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `ID_User2` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `Status_Link` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Leg_Users`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Users` (
  `ID_User` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Lname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(180) NOT NULL,
  `Status` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_User`)
) ;
```

Comment: Please explain what you tried.. Then we can help you solving it.

Comment: you have to join the tables by id_user. you are allowed to join the user table twice for id_user1 and id_user2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT FName, ULName
FROM Friends INNER JOIN
Users ON((ID_User2 = ID_User AND ID_User1 = @User) OR (ID_User1 = ID_User AND ID_User2 = @User))
WHERE Status_Link = 2 -- forgot about that part before...
```

Comment: This only work on half, that's what i did first, but what if the user selected is ID_User2 and not ID_User1. I mean it's only working if you're the one who requests, what if you accept a friend, that means you're as ID_User2 and you still need to see the friend who requested

Comment: see my edited answer. is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

This will return all ID_User2 first and last names when the user = XXX

```
SELECT FName, LName
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Friends f ON u.ID_User = f.ID_User2
WHERE u.ID_User1 = 'XXX'
AND f.Status_Link = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT U.Fname, U.Lname
FROM USERS U 
JOIN FRIENDS F ON F.ID_USER2=U.ID_USER
WHERE F.ID_USER= USER ID OF THE REQUESTED FRIEND LIST
AND F.STATUS_LINK=2 --friends status
```